# How to change certain elements of a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers `x` and another vector of numbers `y`

```
x <- c(0.1,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.12,0.1,0.24,0.05,
     0.03,0.22,0.04,0.003,0.21,0.11,0.44,0.52)

y <- c(0.25,0.054,0.09,.0.93,0.23)
```

I have the order position of the elements within `x` for which I would like to change them by those of `y`.

```
3,5,6,9,14
```

I would like to do this using solely the position of the elements in `x` I would like to change by those of y so I will obtain

```
x <- c(0.1,0.3,0.25,0.3,0.054,0.09,0.24,0.05,
       0.93,0.22,0.04,0.003,0.21,0.23,0.44,0.52)
```

In line with

```
x <- replace(x, (3,5,6,9,14), (0.25,0.054,0.09,.0.93,0.23))
```

many thanks

Comment: Hmm, the edit log is weird... I definitely didn't change from vector to data.frame in my edit

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it went the other way...data frame to vector.

Comment: @RichardScriven, the log says like I've changed it from vector to data.frame, when the only thing i've done is to put the code line into quotes. Wonder how that happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> x <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.12, 0.1, 0.24, 0.05,
         0.03, 0.22, 0.04, 0.003, 0.21, 0.11, 0.44, 0.52)
> y <- c(0.25, 0.054, 0.09, 0.93, 0.23)
```

To change `x` values by your specified indices is simply

```
> x[c(3, 5, 6, 9, 14)] <- y
> x
## [1] 0.100 0.300 0.250 0.300 0.054 0.090 0.240 0.050 
## [9] 0.930 0.220 0.040 0.003 0.210 0.230 0.440 0.520
```

Comment: @Barnaby: On a side note, you can store the positions you want to change in another vector, e.g. `z <- c(3, 5, 6, 9, 14)` and then use this vector in `x[z] <- y` analog to @Richard's answer.